# Best Design Practices if there are more than one views in an Application

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

Hey champs,
This question is for iPad apps designing. 
I searched a lot on this very useful site but i didn't find anything related to the question.

Suppose my application needs to present multiple views to the user, then what is the best way to do that. The ways i think that are possible are

1) Use only one view controller and add all other things as a view.

2) Push all the view controllers on the same viewController.

but if we follow 2nd way, we can not get the desired response to orientation changes.
I am a noob so please spare me on this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our iPad game we are using UIKit therefore we have different views displayed at once. We are using view controllers for most of the views which were then pushed on one specific view to show them.

This keeps the logic code separated in the view controller.

The interaction between the controllers (for example hiding or showing a view after an event) will be done with notifications (`NSNotificationCenter`) to prevent too much dependencies.